# update value in specific row by checking condition for another row, pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I tried a bunch of stuff but nothing seems to work.
See the dataframe.

df

| index | Bool | New_Bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | True |
| 2 | True | True |
| 3 | True | True |
| 4 | False | True |

I want to update a column (`New_bool`). It should contain False if column `Bool` is false already AND it also should contain false in row with `index=1` if `Bool` in row with `index=4` is false as well. All other rows should be kept as are. I cannot manage to do this...see expected output down below.

| index | Bool | New_Bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False |
| 2 | True | True |
| 3 | False | False |
| 4 | False | False |

I tried different combinations of .when statements but that did not work. Best solution so far:

```
df = df.withColumn('New_Bool', F.when((F.col('index')==4) &
                               ((F.col('Bool')==False), False))
```

But this produces:

| index | Bool | New_Bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | None |
| 2 | True | None |
| 3 | True | None |
| 4 | False | False |

If I were able to now fill all Nones with the value from row 4 in `New_Bool` guess that would help. I'd then set up another final column with:

```
df = df.withColumn('Final_Bool', F.when((F.col('index')==1) &
                               ((F.col('New_Bool')==False), False).otherwise(F.col('Bool'))
```

Not sure about anything anymore though because I tried so many combinations....by the way I will have many groups of those dataframes that's why I need a solution that works with groupby or a window function.

Happy for every advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also select the last index's `Bool` value into a variable and use it in when expression like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# or actually, if the index is always = 4 you can just filter without ordering
last_bool = df.orderBy(F.desc("index")).limit(1).select("Bool").first().Bool

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'New_Bool',
    F.when(
        F.col('index') == 1, 
        F.lit(last_bool) & F.col("New_bool") # keep New_bool or update to false if last is false  
    ).otherwise(
        F.col("New_bool") & F.col("Bool") # keep New_bool or update to false if Bool is false 
    )
)

df2.show()
# +-----+-----+--------+
# |index| Bool|New_Bool|
# +-----+-----+--------+
# |    1| true|   false|
# |    2| true|    true|
# |    3|false|   false|
# |    4|false|   false|
# +-----+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead` to check the row with index = 4 when index = 1. For other indices, just keep the bool column.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'New_Bool',
    F.when(
        (F.col('index') == 1) & 
        (F.lead('Bool', 3).over(Window.orderBy('index')) == False),
        False
    ).otherwise(F.col('Bool'))
)

df2.show()
+-----+-----+--------+
|index| Bool|New_Bool|
+-----+-----+--------+
|    1| true|   false|
|    2| true|    true|
|    3|false|   false|
|    4|false|   false|
+-----+-----+--------+
```

Another way is to do a cross join to the bool of the row with index = 4:

```
df2 = df.crossJoin(
    df.filter('index = 4')
      .select(F.col('Bool').alias('id_4'))
).withColumn(
    'New_Bool',
    F.when(
        (F.col('index') == 1) & (F.col('id_4') == False), 
        False
    ).otherwise(F.col('Bool'))
).drop('id_4')
```

If 4 is always the last index, then you can use `last`:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'New_Bool',
    F.when(
        (F.col('index') == 1) & 
        (F.last('Bool').over(Window.orderBy('index').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)) == False),
        False
    ).otherwise(F.col('Bool'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! First solution doesn't work for me cause index 4 isn't neccesarily 3 steps away from index 1 (df could be lacking index 2 for example). 4 will always be last, though. There's no window function using "last", is there?

Solution 2 could be working for me. I will try it. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Bondgirl there is a `last` window function! See my edited answer. That should probably be your best option.

Comment: now I am very confused, I tried to use your method with:
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'New_Bool',
    F.when(
        (F.col('index') == 1) & 
        (F.last('Bool').over(Window.orderBy('index')) == False),
        False
    ).otherwise(F.col('Bool'))
)

but this only duplicates the Bool column and does'nt update the first index, no idea what I am doing wrong if it worked for you

Solution with last_bool gives me an error that I cannot really pin down because I am using databricks-connect and am quite new to all this stuff :o) ...shoot...

Comment: @Bondgirl Ah, I forgot to specify the window frame. The updated answer should be working hopefully. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: @ mck thank you so much! It works perfectly even after I added another partitionby for my groups :o) !